# What is the difference between Weighted Least Square and Generalized Least Square?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, weighted-regression

Weighted least square seems to be a special case of Generalized Least Square. If we have generalized least square technique why do we need to apply weighted least square? or do we call them interchangeably?

Comment: well, weighted least squares is much simpler to implement ...

Comment: So what's the difference?

Comment: Both generalized and weighted LS weights using a matrix of weights $W$.  For generalized LS this is a general (symmetric) matrix, for weighted LS it is diagonal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the errors are dependent,we can use generalized least squares (GLS). When the errors are independent, but not identically distributed, we can use weighted least squares (WLS), which is a special case of GLS.